# NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException when using cache usage:readonly in a domain when testing

Tags: grails

I'm using grails 2.4.2 and hibernate4 4.3.5.4.

When testing a Service with Spock using the HibernateTestMixin if a Domain that is used by the test contains a mapping of "cache usage:readonly", the org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException is thrown.

The error message text is  *"Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given; please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory using the hibernate.cache.region.factory_class setting and make sure the second level cache provider (hibernate-infinispan, e.g.) is available on the classpath."*

The factory_class is set in the DataSource.groovy.  The application runs with no errors and the only issue is when running the test.  If the cache mapping is commented out, the test will run without error.

I also tried to set "hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" to false in the DataSource.groovy file, but the process still throws the same exception.

**Domain.groovy**

```
package tracker

import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
import groovy.transform.ToString

@ToString(includeNames=true, includeFields=true, excludes='metaClass')
@EqualsAndHashCode(includes="transactionId")
class Transaction implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L

    Long transactionId
    Date transactionDate
    String comments

    String userId
    Date activityDate

    static mapping =
    {
        autoTimestamp false
        id column: 'transaction_id', name: 'transactionId', generator: 'sequence', params:[sequence: 'transaction_seq']
        cache usage:'read-only'
        transactionId column: 'transaction_id'
        transactionDate type: 'timestamp'
        activityDate type: 'timestamp'
    }

    static constraints =
    {
        comments(nullable:true, blank:true, maxSize: 2000)
        userId(nullable:true, blank:true, maxSize: 9)
        activityDate(nullable:true)
    }

    Map toMap()
    {
        [
                transactionId : transactionId
            ,   transactionDate : transactionDate
            ,   comments : comments
            ,   version : version
            ,   userId : userId
            ,   activityDate : activityDate
        ]
    }

}
```

**ServiceSpec.groovy**

```
package tracker

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import grails.test.mixin.TestMixin
import grails.test.mixin.gorm.Domain
import grails.test.mixin.hibernate.HibernateTestMixin
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestMixin(HibernateTestMixin)
@TestFor(ReportService)
@Domain( [Transaction, TransType])
class ReportServiceSpec extends Specification {   

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    def createBasicTransactions() {
        new IstTransaction(
                transactionId: 1l,
                transactionDate: new Date().minus(30),
                userId: 'user1',
                activityDate: new Date()
        ).save(failOnError: true, flush: true)

        new IstTransaction(
                transactionId: 2l,
                transactionDate: new Date(),
                userId: 'user2',
                activityDate: new Date()
        ).save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
    }

    void "Test finding transactions with just basic search information"() {

        when: 'No parameter are given'
        createBasicTransactions()

        then:
        IstTransaction.count() == 2
    }
}
```

**BuildConfig.groovy**

```
import grails.util.Environment

grails.servlet.version = "2.5" 
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6

grails.project.fork = false
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven"
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    inherits("global") {
    }
    log "warn" 
    checksums true
    legacyResolve false 

    repositories {
        inherits true
        grailsCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0-grails-2.4"

        compile "commons-pool:commons-pool:1.6"
        compile "commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1"
    }

    plugins {
        build ":tomcat:7.0.54"

        compile ':cache:1.1.7'

        test ":code-coverage:2.0.3-1"

        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.4"
    }
}
```

**DataSource.groovy**

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"
    jmxExport = false
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' 
    singleSession = true
}

// environment specific settings
environments
    {
        development
            {
                dataSource
                    {
                        jndiName = "java:comp/env/jdbc/orcl"
                    }
            }
        test
            {
                dataSource
                    {
                        dbCreate = "update"
                        url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDbBan;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
                    }
            }
        production
            {
                dataSource
                    {
                        jndiName = "java:comp/env/jdbc/orcl"
                    }
    }
}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'TransactionValidator': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given; please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory using the hibernate.cache.region.factory_class setting and make sure the second level cache provider (hibernate-infinispan, e.g.) is available on the classpath.
    at grails.test.runtime.GrailsApplicationTestPlugin$1.initializeContext(GrailsApplicationTestPlugin.groovy:119)
    at grails.test.runtime.GrailsApplicationTestPlugin.createMainContext(GrailsApplicationTestPlugin.groovy:124)
    at grails.test.runtime.GrailsApplicationTestPlugin.initGrailsApplication(GrailsApplicationTestPlugin.groovy:98)
    at grails.test.runtime.GrailsApplicationTestPlugin.onTestEvent(GrailsApplicationTestPlugin.groovy:327)
    at grails.test.runtime.TestRuntime.deliverEvent(TestRuntime.groovy:295)
    at grails.test.runtime.TestRuntime.executeEventLoop(TestRuntime.groovy:280)
    at grails.test.runtime.TestRuntime.processEvents(TestRuntime.groovy:265)
    at grails.test.runtime.TestRuntime.doPublishEvent(TestRuntime.groovy:238)
    at grails.test.runtime.TestRuntime.publishEvent(TestRuntime.groovy:211)
    at grails.test.runtime.TestRuntime.getValue(TestRuntime.groovy:122)
    at grails.test.runtime.GrailsApplicationTestPlugin.onTestEvent(GrailsApplicationTestPlugin.groovy:320)
    at grails.test.runtime.TestRuntime.deliverEvent(TestRuntime.groovy:295)
    at grails.test.runtime.TestRuntime.processEvents(TestRuntime.groovy:264)
    at grails.test.runtime.TestRuntime.doPublishEvent(TestRuntime.groovy:248)
    at grails.test.runtime.TestRuntime.publishEvent(TestRuntime.groovy:211)
    at grails.test.runtime.TestRuntimeJunitAdapter.before(TestRuntimeJunitAdapter.groovy:107)
    at grails.test.runtime.TestRuntimeJunitAdapter$1$2.evaluate(TestRuntimeJunitAdapter.groovy:46)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.TestRuleInterceptor.intercept(TestRuleInterceptor.java:38)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:84)
    at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
    at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:138)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.invokeTargetMethod(MethodInvocation.java:91)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:85)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.AbstractRuleInterceptor$1.evaluate(AbstractRuleInterceptor.java:37)
    at grails.test.runtime.TestRuntimeJunitAdapter$3$4.evaluate(TestRuntimeJunitAdapter.groovy:74)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.ClassRuleInterceptor.intercept(ClassRuleInterceptor.java:38)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:84)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given; please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory using the hibernate.cache.region.factory_class setting and make sure the second level cache provider (hibernate-infinispan, e.g.) is available on the classpath.
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given; please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory using the hibernate.cache.region.factory_class setting and make sure the second level cache provider (hibernate-infinispan, e.g.) is available on the classpath.
    ... 27 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in `grails-datastore-test-support`. I've had a similar thing happen to me so I've opened a bug report at https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11639

Edit: bug was fixed for grails-datastore-test-support v. 1.0.2

Comment: When will version 1.0.2 will be availabe? Can't find it inside the maven repositoy.

Comment: Guessing from the JIRA page I'd say when Grails 2.4.4 is released (I couldn't find any actual date as to when that might be but given that previous versions were released roughly once a month one could guess it is coming soon)

Comment: Grails 2.4.4 was released and grails-datastore-test-support 1.0.2 with it; seems the bug was indeed fixed.